# IAP is not showing in UWP

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I have been working to enable IAP in my UWP, However, it works fine in development mode with XML file (development mode), but it is not showing up in production environment (windows store). I am getting no error in production.
I am using below code to show up all IAPs;

```
    try 
    {    
       ListingInformation listings = await CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync();     
       lstDonation.ItemsSource = listings.ProductListings.Values; 
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {  
       QuranLibrary.MessageService.showMessage(string.Format("Error Occured:
       {0}", ex.Message), QuranLibrary.MessageType.Error);  
    }
```

[image: IAP in Windows Store]

I didn't understand, why it's not showing up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days, it's showing!

Comment: For me it took almost a week,

Comment: Good to know. I am currently trying to add IAP's to my own app, but they are not showing up during enumeration of the StoreProductQueryResult despite their status as showing they are published and in the store. Guess one has to just check periodically until the Add-On is truly "published" and replicated throughout the store.